# JavaScript: extracting string matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, extract

I am trying to extract the GMT number from the following text:

```
All times are GMT -3. The time now is 07:00 PM. Archive
```

I have the code:

```
data = "All times are GMT -3. The time now is 07:00 PM. Archive";
var myregex = /s\GMT([^"]*)./;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(data);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. In this example I am trying to get "-3" into matchArray How can I get the string after the space after GMT and before the period? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you mean `\s`, not ``s\``. There is no `s` in front of `GMT` in your input string, that's why `/s\GMT` doesn't match. Maybe it even tries to match ``\`` literally, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex:

```
var matchArray = /\bGMT *([^.]+)/.exec(data);
if (matchArray)
   console.log(matchArray[1]); //=> -3
```

Comment: what happens if my time is -3.5? how can I make sure it will grab "-3.5"?

Comment: You can use: `/\bGMT +(.+?)(?=\. )/.exec(data);` for that input.

Comment: will that work for both -3 and -3.5? it's a variable so I don't know which number will be there

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this code:

```
var regex = /\bGMT\s+([-+][0-9]+)\b/;
var res = data.match(regex);

console.log(res[1]);
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33reatso/).